# Lazy Line Painter not showing the SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, fullpage.js

My agency are looking to build a new website, and on the homepage we're hoping to use the [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin and the [Lazy Line Painter](http://lazylinepainter.info/) jQuery plugins on the homepage. However, the SVG paths, while being generated/added to the DOM by Lazy Line Painter code, aren't animating. Could the two plugins be clashing?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please create a [mcve]

Comment: Are you initializing the lazy line painter in the `afterRender` callback of fullpage.js? Rad the [fullpage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions) for more info about it.

Comment: Alvaro's cracked it! Not working completely (not very smooth) but I'll ask that as another question. Thanks!